# Highstock Zoom selection not ending

Tags: highcharts

I am using HighStock chart and it is not working for zoom, the zoom selection not ending and not zooming.

http://jsfiddle.net/215f0aua/

```
var chart3 = createChartTemplateForResponseTime();
chart3.addSeries("Response Time");
data3 = graphData[2]
for (var i = 0; i < data3.length; i++) {
chart3.addPoint(data3[i], "Response Time");
$("#response_time_value").html(data3[i][1]+'<span class="txt28">MS</span>');
}
```

Please advice

Comment: Becasue you have an error: "filterResponseTimeSelection is not defined". Run any console (in the browser, developer tools) and you will see it.

Comment: yes, there is an client side error blocking zoom event to work(my side, I have the function filterResponseTimeSelection, but the jtable inside the function causing error)